# Same array pointer for multiple MPI processes

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, mpi

I have the following standard method to create a contiguous 2D array (double)

```
double** array2D (int r, int c)
{
    /*Creates a 2D array*/
    double* B = (double *)malloc(r*c* sizeof(double));
    assert(NULL != B);
    double** A = (double **)malloc(sizeof(double *)*r);
    assert(A);
    A[0] = B;
    for (int i=1; i<=r; i++) A[i] = A[i-1] + c;
    return A;
}
```

Using this function, I am creating arrays of different length for different rank processes in MPI. Here is the code (`numtasks` is the total number of processes and `taskid` is the process rank, `MASTER` is defined as `0`):

```
if (taskid==numtasks-1)
    {
        u_old = array2D(rend+1,c);
        u_new = array2D(rend+1,c);
        MPI_Recv(&u_old[0][0], (rend+1)*c, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, 75, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    }   
    else if(taskid!=0 && taskid!=numtasks-1)
    {
        u_old = array2D(rend+2,c);
        u_new = array2D(rend+2,c);
        MPI_Recv(&u_old[0][0], (rend+2)*c, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, 75, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    }
```

Say when I am running this part of the code with 4 processes, the `else if` block is run by processes 1 and 2. While using the Arm DDT debugger, I saw that the `u_old` and `u_new` for both processes 1 and 2 have the same memory address (**I didn't expect this!**) while, process 3 has a different address for `u_old` and `u_new` as I expected. How can I make the processes 1 and 2 have different memory locations for their individual `u_old` and `u_new`?

Comment: This does not answer your question, but should `for (int i=1; i<=r; i++)` be `for (int i=1; i<r; i++)`?

Comment: maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978222/mpi-and-global-object-all-ranks-have-the-object-at-same-memory-address ? Its not possible many processes to have the same address .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MPI and global object: All ranks have the object at same memory address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978222/mpi-and-global-object-all-ranks-have-the-object-at-same-memory-address)

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the MPI model. Each process has a completely distinct memory space even if they're all on the same physical multicore machine. So processes 1 and 2 *do not* have the same physical memory address for the arrays. They may have the same virtual address (which is what you print out or see via the debugger) but this will map to different physical addresses. Why do you care what the virtual memory addresses are?